# Teradata: How to display LOB inline(inside the cells)

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a Teradata table which contains LOB objects in different columns.

When I do a query, it pops up window to ask where to save the LOB objects as txt files onto my disk.

[LOB Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdMsg.png) (due to my SOF level, I cannot display the screenshot)

My question is, is it possible to display the content of these LOB objects inline(inside the cells)?

Comment: If you click "Cancel" on that pop-up then SQL Assistant will attempt to display the data inline. Might have trouble if the values being retrieved are quite large. Also note there is a setting under Tools / Options / Data Format that causes SQL Assistant to act as if VARCHAR columns above a certain max length are CLOBs.

Comment: Clicking Cancel doesn't make the content displayed inline, it just became a question mark.

Comment: Then it seems like the content of that column is NULL. You could confirm using `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` or by checking `LENGTH(clob_column)` which would return NULL instead of a numeric length.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

[Changed Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ydT.png)
(Due to my SOF level, I cannot show image directly in my post)

Changing the "Handle the BLOB/CLOB size" to smaller values solved my problem partially.

The reason why it's partially is because the LOB Information pop-up still there.

Comment: Hard to see how generating a pop-up for (nearly) every VARCHAR column would be an improvement / partial solution. No, I don't think there is a way to avoid the pop-up if the data type is actually CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for viewing in Teradata SQL Assistant only (it can't display arbitrarily wide columns):

If the strings in the CLOB columns are short enough, cast them to varchar in your query:

```
select id, cast(clarge as varchar(1000)) as WhatIsInCLob
from ...
```

If the values can exceed varchar limits (depends on the character set of the CLOB, and session character settings, but easily thousands of chars), then use SUBSTRING to limit the output:

```
select id, cast(substring(clarge,1,4000) as varchar(4000)) as WhatIsInCLob
from ...
```

There is more specific limit information here: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-SQL-Assistant-for-Windows-User-Guide/October-2018/Getting-Started/Limitations